# Access Object using Index in .find() in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to access an object using index notation in typescript. But I cannot find a way that keeps my types (without using any).

In typescript I get the following error (strict mode):

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type '{ givenName: string; familyName:
>   string; email: string; active: boolean; }'.
>
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on
>   type '{ givenName: string; familyName: string; email: string; active:
>   boolean; }'.

```
// Example document
interface user {
  givenName: string
  familyName: string
  email: string
  active: boolean
}

const user:user = {
  givenName: 'Max',
  familyName: 'Maier',
  email: 'max.maier@example.com',
  active: true,
}

// To be used like this
const match = ['givenName', 'familyName', 'email'].find(e => 
    !!user[e] && user[e].toLowerCase().includes('searchQuery')
)
```

there are no errors when using a static string.

```
!!user['givenName'] && user['givenName'].toLowerCase().includes('searchQuery')
```

Defining an indexer seems to always throw me into the problem of loosing type safety. E.g.

```
[index: string]: string | boolean | undefined
```

will give an error with the `.toLowerCase()` . I could fix it using `any` but that is not what I want.

In my opinion the best solution would be to make typescript understand that `e` is an existing index with something like this:

```
['givenName', 'familyName', 'email'].find((e:'givenName'| 'familyName'| 'email' ) =>
```

But I failed getting the error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"givenName" | "familyName" | "email"'

I'm able to hack it using any but I can't figure out type safe way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way

```
const match = (['givenName', 'familyName', 'email'] as const).find(e => 
    !!user[e] && user[e].toLowerCase().includes('searchQuery')
)
```

Then the array is typed as an array of union of literals, not just as a `string[]` and the `e` is properly typed as a union of literals correspondingly.

References:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions